# Unity drag and drop check right or left (2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanna build a card game in Unity.
I want to player swipe cards left or right but I wanna show some tricks about what's gonna happen if they swipe left or right so if they grab the card (2D Image) and go a bit left or right a text will appear on image depends on side.
I tried to use swipe and use X axis change but It's not working properly.

Here is a basic pictured information about what i wanna build:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise using the drag handlers system in unity to track where the card started, and trigger different effects at different distances / directions from its origin.

You can detect the drag of the card by implementing **IBeginDragHandler**, **IDragHandler**, **IEndDragHandler** on a script on your card object.

**Begin** is called when the object starts dragging, **Drag** is called during each frame its moving, and **End** is called when the object is dropped.

When a drag begins, you can cache the position where the card started. Then in Drag handler each frame you can check the distance of your card from where it started. Once it has moved more than a certain distance, you can trigger whatever tricks or effects you want to show.

Depending on how your coordinate space is set up, you could for example know left from right during drag updates such as:

```
// Inside of your on drag method, check each frame for where the card is
// If it has moved far enough, trigger an effect
if (Vector3.Distance(dragStartPosition, transfom.position) > yourTriggerDistance) {
    // if X is greater, the card moved right
    if (transform.position.x > dragStartPosition.x) {
        // Trigger Right swipe text
        ShowSomeRightSwipeText();
    }
    // otherwise, X is smaller, so the card has moved left by the required distance
    else {
        // Trigger left swipe text
        ShowSomeLeftSwipeText();
    }
}
```

Also please remember that:

- In order for these interfaces to work, you need to have a **Physics 2D Raycaster** attached to your camera in the scene.
- You need to make sure you have an **Event System** in the scene as well.

The above two things are often asked issues here regarding detecting object dragging.